# Wix: Change the font color of the text in the header in standard dialog

Tags: wix

I'm using WIX to create my msi. I would like to change the font color of the text in the header.  For exemple, I would like to change the text of the control "Title" in the Dialog "SetupTypeDlg".  I tried with that, but doesn't work.

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" Codepage="1252" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <UI Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Title" >{\HeaderTitleFont}!(loc.SetupTypeDlgTitle)</UI>
</WixLocalization>
```

But it can't find the value of !(loc.SetupTypeDlgTitle). It shows that text exactly.  Any idea ? Is it possible ?  I want to avoid to copy paste all header string in my side to add the font color. Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution? how to change dialog title in WIX installer? its many many appreciation if any one give the solution.. Thanks in advance.